# Rest API PUT/PATCH method should the model contain the full data or reflect only changes

Tags: api, rest, .net-core

let's imaging Customer model looks lie this:

```
Customer{

 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string FirstName {get;set;}
 public string LastName{get;set;}
 public Company {get;set;}

}
```

GET endpoint looks like this:

```
[HttpGet, Route("{id}")]
GetById(int id)
 var entity = dataService.GetById(id);
 var model = Mapper.Map<Entity,Customer>(entity, model);
 return model;
```

model data provided by get endpoint:

```
 {{ Id: 1, FirstName : 'John', LastName:'Dow', Company: {...} }}
```

let's say user edited first name only:

```
{{ Id: 1, FirstName : 'Mike', LastName:'Dow', Company: {...} }}
```

PUT endpoint (classic .net approach):

```
[HttpPut, Route("{id}")]
Update(int id, Customer model)
```

the model data is expected as

```
{{ Id: 1, FirstName : 'Mike', LastName:'Dow', Company: {...} }}
```

But what i've got on my endpoint frontend submits only changes in data, i.e. properties that user has edited the rest is null or 0:

{{ Id: 0, FirstName : 'Mike', LastName: null, Company: null }}

```
[HttpPut, Route("{id}")]
Update(int id, Customer model) // where model means changes-only
```

so the backend should put if conditions for each property to do the mapping from model to entity:

```
if(model.FirstName !=null)
   entity.FirstName  = model.FirstName;


if(model.LastName !=null)
   entity.LastName = model.LastName;
```

**My questions are**

1. from the REST API perspective, the PUT endpoint whether it is said anything on what model should contain the full data or partial data (changes) is also possible?

as for me it looks the verb should be PATCH in case we expect partial data i.e. changes only

2. which approach u use nowadays? - the second one looks as something new for me  but it smells due to many if statements. I wondered if .NET core team introduced it recently, or this comes into .NET world from frontend..

can't decide whether i should agree and accept the new approach or say no this smell with if statements makes me crazy=))

Answer (score 0):

> A successful PUT of a given representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same target resource will result in an equivalent representation being sent in a 200 (OK) response. -- [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-put)

So

```
PUT /customer/2
Content-Type: application/json

{{ Id: 0, FirstName : 'Mike', LastName: null, Company: null }}
```

Means "make the representation of /customer/2 look like this document (with the nulls and the zero id)", just as it would mean for any other resource on the internet.  That's the whole point of "uniform interface" - everybody understands the same messages the same way.

What the server *does* with the request is an implementation detail, and not constrained by HTTP (keeping in mind that the server is responsible for any [loss of property](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html) caused by the deviations from the standard meanings)

---

If the intent of the request is a partial change to the representation of the resource, and you want general purpose components to understand the message, then you should be describing the changes with a representation of a patch document (ex: application/merge-patch+json), and using the PATCH method.